# Eliminating transient values in OSIsoft PI Datalink for Excel

Tags: excel, osisoft

Is there a way to filter data based on the time-elapsed with PI-Excel interface. For example, I have data on PI for 1 hour and I want to find the maximum value of this data. However, I want the program to ignore transient values, that is values that only last for 2 seconds. If I could filter those transient values (that is values greater than 2  seconds), I would then want to find the maximum of these values. Please help out! Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find some plant data on my PI server that was analogous to your situation so that I could give you an exact equation, but could not find any.

However, when you pull data in PI Datalink you have the option of adding Filter Expressions on most data pull types (Compressed, Sampled, Timed, and Calculated).

Here is a link to Filter Expression syntax rules from OSISoft:

https://livelibrary.osisoft.com/LiveLibrary/content/en/datalink-v6/GUID-48F4D820-DA88-4C7F-A07E-525EC0DC22DC

Here is a solved question from the PI Square Community:

https://pisquare.osisoft.com/thread/9071

I would recommend utilizing PISquare in the future for questions like these as you are much more likely to get a fast response. OSISoft also provides very good training videos and resources on their website/youtube channel.